# Why this shortest pathfinding algorithm not working?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, path-finding

Trying to find the shortest path through a dynamic programming approach
but it doesn't seem to be working below is the code of the algorithm and the graph class.

I tired to store the paths through a memo technique as well as the costs so redundant calculations won't happen but still it gives me maximum recursion depth and don't find the shortest path.

```
class Graph:
  def __init__(self):
      self.nodes = dict()

  def add_edge(self, p, c, weight):
    if self.nodes.get(p, -1) == -1 or self.nodes.get(c, -1) == -1:
      return

    self.nodes[p].append((c, weight))
    self.nodes[c].append((p, weight))

  def add_node(self, n):
    if self.nodes.get(n, -1) != -1:
      return 

    self.nodes[n] = []

  def is_adjacent(self, a, b):
     for i in self.nodes[a]:
      if i[0] == b:
        return True

     return False



def weight(graph, a, b):
  if graph.is_adjacent(a, b) == False:
    return "Not adjacent"

  for i in graph.nodes[a]:
    if i[0] == b:
      return i[1]


def path_length(graph, path):
  sum = 0
  for i in  range(0, len(path) - 1):
    
    if weight(graph, path[i] , path[i + 1]) == "Not adjacent":
      return "Invalid path"

    sum = sum + weight(graph, path[i], path[i + 1])

  return sum


memo = dict()
costs = dict()

def shortest_path(graph, root, target):
    if memo.get(root + ' , ' + target, -1) != -1:
      return memo[root + ' , ' + target]

    if root == target:
      memo[root + ' , ' + target] = [root]
      costs[ [root] ] = 0
      return memo[root + ' , ' + target]

    if graph.nodes[root] == []:            #childless node
      memo[root + ' , ' + target] = []
      return memo[root + ' , ' + target]

    spaths = []  # spaths is a list for shortest paths from adjacent nodes
    for i in graph.nodes[root]:
      adjacent_node = i[0]
      spaths.append( shortest_path(graph , adjacent_node, target) )

    shortestPath = []
    minimum_cost = 1000000000

    for i in spaths:
      if i[-1] != target or i == []:
        continue

      if costs.get(i, -1) == - 1:
        if  minimum_cost > path_length(graph, i) + weight(graph, root, i[0]):
            minimum_cost = path_length(graph, i) + weight(graph ,root, i[0])

            costs[i] = path_length(graph, i)
        
            shortestPath = []
            shortestPath.append(root)
            for j in i:
              shortestPath.append(j)

      if costs[i] + weight(graph, root, i[0]) > minimum_cost:
        minimum_cost = costs[i] + weight(graph, root, i[0])

        shortestPath = []
        shortestPath.append(root)
        for j in i:
              shortestPath.append(j)

    memo[root + ' , ' + target] = shortestPath

    return memo[root + ' , ' + target]

nodes_ =  {
    'A' : [ ('B', 4) , ('H', 8) ],
    'B' : [ ('A', 4) ,  ('C', 8) , ('H', 11)],
    'C'  :[ ('B', 8), ('D', 7), ('F', 4), ('I', 2)],
    'D' : [ ('C', 7), ('E', 9), ('F', 14)],
    'E' : [('D', 9), ('F', 10)],
    'F' : [('C', 4), ('D', 14), ('E', 10), ('G', 2)],
    'G' : [('F', 2), ('H', 1), ('I', 6)],
    'H' : [('A', 8), ('B', 11) ,('G', 1), ('I', 7)],
    'I' : [('C', 2), ('G', 6), ('H', 7)]
}

g = Graph()
g.nodes = nodes_

shortest_path(g, 'A', 'I')
```

When I try the code it gives me maximum recursion depth

Comment: https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/tower-defense/ might want to review your graph theory. You can memoize in python using @functools.lru_cache. This will remove some of the clutter from your code.

Comment: Please provide the code that actually calls your functions and leads to the error you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the infinite recursion is here:

```
    for i in graph.nodes[root]:
      adjacent_node = i[0]
      spaths.append( shortest_path(graph , adjacent_node, target) )
```

Since your graph is undirected, if node  has  as neighbor, then  has  as neighbor. If they are eachother's *first* neighbor, then you get stuck in a recursion loop.

This is the case for your example graph: the first neighbor of node 'A' is node 'B', and vice versa. `root` is first equal to 'A', and `i[0]` will be 'B'. A recursive call is then made with `root` equal to 'B'. And now the opposite happens: `i[0]` is now 'A', and a recursive call is made that doesn't bring us any closer to a solution, but just repeats the same cycle.

Another issue is that your code would try to use a list as a key in the dictionary `c`, but that is not possible. You cannot use a list as a dictionary key.

Not a problem, but you seem to use this pattern a lot:

```
if self.nodes.get(n, -1) != -1:
```

You can do this simply with the `in` operator:

```
if n in self.nodes:
```

#### Dijkstra's algorithm

It is one of the most mentioned algorithms on this site when dealing with shortest path problems. You can find hundreds of implementations on Stack Overflow. I will present one here that uses your `Graph` data structure, and `heapq` for the priority queue that is typical for Dijkstra's algorithm:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def shortest_path(graph, root, target):
    heap = [(0, root, None)]  # weight, node, previousnode
    camefrom = {}
    
    while heap:
        cost, node, previousnode = heappop(heap)
        if node == target:
            # bingo! unwind path
            path = [target]
            while previousnode:
                path.append(previousnode)
                previousnode = camefrom[previousnode]
            return path[::-1]
        if node not in camefrom:
            camefrom[node] = previousnode
            for neighbor, weight in graph.nodes[node]:
                if neighbor not in camefrom:
                    heappush(heap, (cost + weight, neighbor, node))
```

For your example graph this will return ['A', 'B', 'C', 'I'].